# Transform complicate logic to stream/optional

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to transform below codes (a lot of if/for/null check) to stream/optional. Been trying for a while but cannot make it right. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
    String id = null;
    String res = null;
    List<ShoppingCandidate> shoppingCandidates = null;
    List<DiscoveredIdentity> discoveredIdentityList = null;
    Optional<DiscoveredIdentities> discoveredIdentities = contextAccessor.maybeAccess(DiscoveredIdentities.class);
    Optional<DiscoveredShoppingCandidates> discoveredShoppingCandidates = contextAccessor.maybeAccess(DiscoveredShoppingCandidates.class);
    
    if(discoveredShoppingCandidates.isPresent()){
        shoppingCandidates = discoveredShoppingCandidates.get().getShoppingCandidates();
    }
    if(shoppingCandidates != null){
        for(ShoppingCandidate shoppingCandidate : shoppingCandidates){
            if(shoppingCandidate.getIdentityReferenceList() != null){
                for(IdentityReference identityReference : shoppingCandidate.getIdentityReferenceList()){
                    if(identityReference.getIdRole().equals("123")){
                        id = identityReference.getReferenceId();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    if(discoveredIdentities.isPresent()){
        discoveredIdentityList = discoveredIdentities.get().getDiscoveredIdentityList();
        if(discoveredIdentityList != null){
            for(DiscoveredIdentity discoveredIdentity : discoveredIdentityList){
                if(discoveredIdentity.getIdentityId().equals(id)){
                    List<IdentityKey> identityKeyList = discoveredIdentity.getIdentityKeyList();
                    if(identityKeyList != null){
                        for(IdentityKey key: identityKeyList){
                            if(key.getIdType().equals("CID")){
                                res = key.getId();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not safe as long as you might end up with `id` as `null` and the subsequent checks based on it would be invalid.

Also using `Optional::isPresent` is just a disguise of the procedural `if-else`. Can you find the difference?

```
if (something != null) {
   // use something
}
```

```
if (optionalSomething.isPresent()) {
   // use optionalSomething.get();
}
```

There is no difference. The power of `Optional` is in the usage of chaining method such as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `orElse` etc.

If you try to "convert" the procedural `if-else-for-each` code into something based on the correct usage of `Optional`, you might result in something like below. It is still very clumsy and honestly, the difference is not visible as it should be, although the correct methods were used. The maintainability is still questioned as long as the complicated structure and logics.

In my opinion, `Optional` would not help you in this case to achieve maintainability and clarity. The only advantage you gain is handling the situation when the `id` is not found (ie. is `null`).

What I recommend you is to extract the logic pieces into a separate methods to achieve a clean code.

Finally, take a look (untested, but it gives you an idea):

```
String res = discoveredShoppingCandidates
       .map(DiscoveredShoppingCandidates::getShoppingCandidates)
       .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
       .stream()
       .map(ShoppingCandidate::getIdentityReferenceList)
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
       .filter(s -> "123".equals(s.getIdRole()))
       .map(IdentityReference::getReferenceId)
       .flatMap(id -> discoveredIdentities
               .map(DiscoveredIdentities::getDiscoveredIdentityList)
               .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
               .stream()
               .filter(s -> Objects.equals(id, s.getIdentityId()))
               .flatMap(s -> s.getIdentityKeyList().stream())
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .filter(s -> "CID".equals(s.getIdType()))
               .map(IdentityKey::getId))
       .findFirst()
       .orElse(null);
```